# Implementing client credentials (JWT Bearer Token) into an Angular 2+ client app

Tags: angular, oauth, openid-connect

I'm setting up an Angular 7 client application to

1. Read An excel spreadsheet
2. Parse the data in excel
3. Get a JWT Bearer token from our OpenId Connect server
4. Use that token to access an internal API with the data from the excel file

What is the best way to get a JWT Bearer token in Angular? I'm not finding anything specific in the docs. We use IdentityServer if that matters.

I've tried installing a multitude of NPM packages to help authenticate with OpenId but it seems that all of the libraries I've tried only implement implicit flow.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you wouldn't implement the client_credentials flow on the angular side of the app. Getting a client token directly through the front-end would necessarily expose your client secret; no? That may be why all the angular packages only support implicit.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the terminology here, but in Swagger it automatically implements the ability to add Client Credentials through the Swagger GUI.

This is basically what I'm trying to implement with Angular. A spot for a user to log in and input the password for the client.

BTW, this is an internal service and will never be available externally.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Backend server? I can provide you some code sample to implement JWT in Angular with ASP.NET Core as backend.
Meanwhile you can also have a look at https://medium.com/@amcdnl/authentication-in-angular-jwt-c1067495c5e0

Comment: I don't have a backend. This is 100% driven by the excel file which I parse on the client side.

I use IdentityServer3 running on .net framework for the oauth portion though

Answer (score 0):

i recommand using  [@auth0/angular-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) , it has very useful helpers

- you can check whenever your token has expired
- your access token is send automatically on every Http call to the server inside the header

Comment: this might be just what I was looking for! I'll give it a shot and edit this if it works